# How to open a .bat file during the test execution in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I would like to open a .bat file in windows folder during the test in Cypress.

For example,

```
describe("open a file", () => {
  it("open a bat file", () => {
    xxx;
    xxx;
  })
})
```

Someone said can use

```
const wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      wshShell.Run("D:\\dir\\user.bat");
```

but it has error here to find the ActiveXObject. How to import it? Or there is a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try [cy.exec](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec) command:

```js
describe("open a file", () => {
  it("open a bat file", () => {
    cy.exec("D:\\dir\\user.bat");
    xxx;
  })
})
```

Comment: I am able to open the bat file. However, it seems not able to move forward. Test fails because of the timed out after waiting 60000ms.

Comment: does the bat file finish quickly when you run it from the command line?

Comment: This bat file is used to open a .exe file. And I need to keep this application open during the test execution. So I am not sure if I can say "finish".

Comment: The docs do not recommend to start an application within the cypress process:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Web-Servers